# Unable to access Dlink router admin page

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, isp

Was trying to access control list (ACL) page on my D-Link router, and suddenly after saving I'm unable to access the router admin page. Everything else is working, my internet is working, just that I'm not able to access the admin page for other changes. Browser simply throws a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: If SSH is enabled, you may be able to log in via that and fix the ACL. But if you've locked yourself out, there is no easy way to get back in - if there was your router would be insecure...

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reset your router, here's how:

To reset your D-Link router:
With the power on (Power LED on front panel should be lit green), use the pointed end of a paper clip to press and hold the Reset button for 10 seconds.

Release the Reset button. The D-Link router will automatically reboot itself.

Wait 15 seconds before resuming setup.

Your D-Link router is now using the default settings for the network configuration. This includes the default SSID and WEP encryption key. You must re-configure your D-Link router to match the previous settings that were assigned to all the other devices on your wireless network. Otherwise, no other network devices will be recognized.